# Using browser module to submit form in node.js

Tags: forms, node.js, http, browser, submit

I used the browser module (https://github.com/shinout/browser) to test form submission in node.js and it was successful by running the following code:

```
var $b = new browser();
$b.submit({
  from : 'https://accounts.google.com/Login',
  selector: "#gaia_loginform",
  data : {
    Email  : "XXXXXX@gmail.com",
    Passwd : "XXXXXXXX"
  }
});

// authenticated access
$b.browse('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=html&zy=d')
.after(); // browse after previously registered function

$b.on("end", function(err, out) {
  console.log(out.url, out.result, out.responseHeaders);
});

$b.run();
```

But when I add additional code after $b.run()

```
$b.browse('https://mail.google.com').after();
$b.run();
```

I got the following error:

```
Junjo.register cannot be called when the template is frozen.
```

I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to read from sources, the browser module does not support running multiple jobs with single browser instance. Method `$b.run()` marks the object as frozen, which causes methods like `browse` to throw the error you are getting.

Comment: The first $b.run() stored the cookies I want in $b. What should I do if I want to use the cookies later? Thanks.

Comment: Can I call $b.run() again after I called $b.run()? Awaiting for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try to call $b.run() again yourself? But it seems like the first call sets a flag and the second call does nothing. I thought you would want to reuse cookies, but I didn't find a way how to do that :( Why don't you write an e-mail to the author of browser module? https://github.com/shinout